# Classes using inheritance in java

Tags: java, inheritance

I am fairly new Java and am working on a project that uses inheritance. There are three different classes right now - A top level `Car` class, a mid level `CarPart` class, and a lower level `Engine` class that inherits the CarPart class. I want the Engine class to just represent the component behavior/state. I want the CarPart class to be generic - to work with multiple different parts (right now I only have Engine set up). Right now, I want every class representing a car part (like the engine) to inherit from a superclass called "CarPart." The CarPart class will have all of the states and behaviors that are shared by all types of car parts (like condition and the ability to print a diagnostic report).

Below is my Car class where I want to be able to create the part objects

```
public class Car {
  Engine engine;

  public Car() {
    engine = new Engine();
  }

  public void run() {
    this.engine.printStatus();
  }
}
```

Below is my CarPart class that I want to be generic to any type of car part and for now I just want to print the state of the part.

```
public class CarPart {
  private Object object; 

  public String printState(Object object) {
    System.out.println("The status is "+object.getState());
  }

}
```

Below is the code for my Engine class:

```
public class Engine extends CarPart{
  private String state;

  public String getState() {
    if(!state.equals(null)) {
        System.out.println("The engine is "+state);
    } else {
        this.state = "off";
        System.out.println("The engine is off");
    }
    return state;
  }

  public void setState(String engineState) {
    this.state = engineState;
  }
}
```

I think the problem has to do with downcasting and the parent class not having access to methods in the child class - but I'm not sure how to go about printing a status report the correct way. Any advice would be much appreciated!

Comment: `public String printState(Object object)` So you can print the state of ANY object (String, Integer, ArrayList, John3136sSuperDuperSwissArmyKnifeClassOfPain) ?

Comment: @John3136 sorry, forgot to add that. No I don't know how to print the state of any object from CarPart. I get the error that "getState() is undefined for type Object"

Comment: CarPart and Engine should have constructors.

Comment: You have not actually asked a question or provided any details of your problem. At a guess the `printState` should use `CarPart` instead of `Object` and you need to add the state to the `CarPart` not the `Engine`

Comment: @Cppplus1 what would the constructor for CarPart have in it?

Comment: @kdubs A value to set state equal to.

Comment: Before a constructor will help, `CarPart` needs state - all of that is currently down in `Engine` instead of `CarPart`

Comment: @kdubs objects from the class `Object` don't have the method getState, but `CarPart` does. Don't use`Object`s, use `public String printState(CarPart carPart) { System.out.println("The status is "+object.getState()); }`

Comment: @John3136 Oh ok, so it would be better to have the getters/setters in CarPart and then just store the actual part information in the child classes?

Comment: @kdubs or not... Are you sure *ALL* CarParts would have that structure? Maybe there's a CarPart with more attributes, or none at all. Implement it in a way that any CarPart can be as it needs to be. So, the responsibility for get/set is of the Engine, not CarPart. In CarPart you should have only the *things* (methods, attributes) that EVERY CarPart should have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move `getState()`, `setState()` and the `state` member out of `Engine` "up into" `CarPart`

`CarPart`'s `printState(Object object) {` becomes:

```
public void printState()
{ 
    System.out.println(this.state);
}
```

You have not given us enough info to much further. e.g.You could just give each `CarPart` a name and not bother with subclasses. Subclasses like `Engine` only make sense if you are going to add data and/or functionality to them. e.g. an `Engine` has a number of cylinders, perhaps a power output, maybe a fuel type. A `WindscreenWiper` doesn't have any of those properties.

Also note that `printState` is probably not what you want. You'd normally have the `Car` go through all of it's `CarPart`s and call `getState()` on each one so that the `Car` can format how the printing is done.

Comment: The next step was to add specific information like that to the subclasses so that is why I set it up like that. I was just trying to get a bare bones version working first.

Comment: Well, if doesn't answer the question, you need to be more specific about what isn't working and what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

Note: I myself am a beginner at java, so I may not be 100% correct.

From what I've understood on inheritance, the object reference type (type of the reference variable, not of the object being referred to) determines which methods are available to be implemented on the object. For example, the reference variable Object object can only use methods defined in the Object class (which is the superclass of all java classes). However, you cannot call the getState() method on an Object object since this method is not included in the Object class. getState() is defined in the subclass Engine, and thus is only available to Engine objects.

As such, I'd recommend you making the CarPart class abstract and implementing abstact methods getState() and printState() in that class, and then override these methods in each of its subclasses (corresponding to each car part).

```
class abstract CarPart {
    abstract String printState(Object object); 
    abstract String getState();
}

class Engine extends CarPart {
    String getState() {
        //code
    }

    String printState() {
        //code
    }
}
```

Also, since you'll eventually have more than just the Engine subclass, I'd recommend simply creating each object from that part's individual class instead of creating a car class to do this. There may be a more efficient method to do this using a single class to create objects of different types, but I am currently unaware of it.

Answer (score -1):

Since your error message is "getState() is undefined for type Object", it's because of:

```
public class CarPart {
    private Object object; 
    public String printState(Object object) {
        System.out.println("The status is "+object.getState());
    }
}
```

In the 4th line you used a method of `Engine` on an `Object` reference.
The `Object` class doesn't have that method, so it's invalid. You can either cast it as `System.out.println("The status is "+((Engine)object).getState());` (but you could get one Exception if the object is not a `Engine`) or change your classes.

```
public class Car {
    private Engine engine;
    public void run() {
        System.out.println( engine.getState() );
    }
}
public abstract class CarPart {
    public String getState();
}
public class Engine extends CarPart {
    private String state;
    public String getState(){
        if( state== null ) state= "off";
        return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be nice to know the reason of the down vote, so I can improve my coding skills. If you can, please tell me why you down voted my answer.

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but maybe it is because you didn't really solve the person's problem you just suggested a whole different approach.

Comment: @csm_dev good point. But I gave him a "answer" in the comments... I will try to clarify it. Thanks!